# Multiply permutations of two vectors in R

Tags: r, permutation, vector-multiplication

I've got two vectors of the length 4 and want a multiplication of the permutations of the vector:

```
A=(a1,a2,a3,a4)
B=(b1,b2,b3,b4)
```

I want:

```
a1*b1;a1*b2;a1*b3...a4*b4
```

as a list with known order or data.frame with row.names=A and colnames=B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `outer(A,B,'*')` which will return a matrix

```
x<-c(1:4)
y<-c(10:14)
outer(x,y,'*')
```

returns

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   10   11   12   13   14
[2,]   20   22   24   26   28
[3,]   30   33   36   39   42
[4,]   40   44   48   52   56
```

and if you want the result in a list you then can do

```
z<-outer(x,y,'*')
z.list<-as.list(t(z))
```

`head(z.list)` returns

```
[[1]]
[1] 10

[[2]]
[1] 11

[[3]]
[1] 12

[[4]]
[1] 13

[[5]]
[1] 14

[[6]]
[1] 20
```

which is x1*y1, x1*y2, x1* y3, x1*y4, x2*y1 ,... (if you want x1*y1, x2*y1, ... replace `t(z)` by `z`)

Comment: for my purpose "melt" from the reshape2 package did a good job after the outer(A,B) command

Comment: `expand.grid` is more efficient than `melt(outer()))`

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `expand.grid` or `outer`

```
combination <- expand.grid(A, B)
combination$Result <- combination$A * combination$B
outer(A, B, FUN = "*")
```

Comment: In `outer` the default argument of `FUN` is `"*"`, so just `outer(A,B)` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

We can try `vapply`:

```
vapply(B, '*', A, FUN.VALUE=numeric(length(A)))
```